# Set selected value for nested form in ASP.NET MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have a model which has a collection of users. I'm looping through this collection to generate a table of users. One of the options in the table is to change the user's role, which is an enum property of the user object. Currently I have the following code:

```
@foreach (var user in Model.Users) 
{ 
    <tr>
        ...
        <td>
            <form action="@Url.Action("UpdateRole", "Admin", new { id = user.Id })" class="inline">
                @Html.DropDownList("Role", Model.GetRoles())
            </form>                    
        </td>
        ...
    </tr>
}
```

The problem with this code is that the generated drop down list is unaware of the actual value of the property on the user object. However, I see no overload for the DropDownList method that accepts a value to use for the selected value. The DropDownListFor method does, but it appears to operate directly on the model, and I can't figure out a way to pass it the type of the nested user object. Can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `SelectList` [[1]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.selectlist%28v=vs.98%29.aspx) which has an override for the selected value, e.g.:

```
@Html.DropDownList("Role", new SelectList(Model.GetRoles(), "selectedValueHere"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom DropDownList HtmlHelper extension method that includes the options that you need.

Comment: Creating a proper html helper for something like this is non-trivial, and I'm hoping to avoid it. Worst case scenario, I move the entire contents of the foreach loop to a partial view and render it that way. I was hoping for a simple way to shim the correct value into the existing helper method before I do that though.

Comment: It actually is pretty trivial if you use Reflector and look at `System.Web.Mvc.Html.SelectExtensions`.  Another solution (although a bit hacky), would be to create an extension method that does client-side binding with jQuery, and call that immediately after declaring the dropdown